# Will the following expression be irrational, rational or integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Will the following expression be irrational, rational or integer?

$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt a +b} - \sqrt[3]{\sqrt a -b}$$

where $a$ = $52$ and $b$ = $5$ .

By intuition, I think this will be an integer.

Comment: It certainly depends on $a,b$. For example, take $a=b=0$, then the expression is $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Take $a=b=1$ and the expression is $2^{1/3}$ which is irrational.

Comment: @Bazinga I've added LaTeXed version of your formula. If this is what you meant, you can edit the post ant leave the LaTeX-ed version there. For more about writing math at this site see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Given any natural $a,b$, it will be an algebraic integer, therefore either integer or irrational.

Comment: Instead of saying "irrational, rational or integer", it may be more useful to say "irrational, non-integer rational, or integer".

Comment: Can the cube-root $(5+\sqrt{52})^{1/3}$ be written in the form $x+y\sqrt{52}$ with rational $x,y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the identity $(\alpha + \beta)^3 = \alpha^3+\beta^3+3\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)$

Set $\alpha =\sqrt[3]{b+\sqrt{a}} \text{ and } \beta= \sqrt[3]{b - \sqrt{a}} \text { and } \alpha+\beta=x$

We know that $\alpha\beta = \sqrt[3]{b+\sqrt{a}} \times \sqrt[3]{b - \sqrt{a}} = \sqrt[3]{b^2-a} = \sqrt[3]{25-52} = -3$

So $x^3= b+\sqrt a + b-\sqrt a - 9x = 2b-9x = 10-9x$

You know that you are looking for a real answer, because $a$ is positive and the two cube roots are therefore cube roots of real numbers. Arturo has factorised the cubic, but it is easy to see that 1 is a root (integer roots must be divisors of 10).

Answer (score 4):

The expression quickly brings to my mind the Cardano formulas for a (depressed) cubic. Which suggested the following:

We can rewrite as
$$\sqrt[3]{b+\sqrt{a}} + \sqrt[3]{b - \sqrt{a}}.$$
This is a root of the cubic $y^3 + 3py + q=0$, where
$b = \frac{-q}{2}$ and $a=\frac{q^2+4p^3}{4}$.

With $b=5$, we have $q=-10$, so
$$52 = a = \frac{100+4p^3}{4}.$$
This gives $4p^3 = 208-100 = 108$, so $p^3 = 27$, or $p=3$.

Thus, the expression at hand is a root of the cubic
$$y^3 + 9y -10 = 0.$$
This cubic has an obvious integer root $y=1$ (or you could use the rational root test to see if it has any rational roots if this is not obvious), which after factoring gives
$$y^3 + 9y - 10 = (y-1)(y^2 + y+10).$$
The quadratic is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$, so its roots are complex.

Assuming you mean the *real* cubic roots of the real numbers, since our number is real, it must equal $1$.